# Login to Javascript with Python Phantomjs

Tags: python

Does any one have a basic example of using [PhantomJs](http://www.phantomjs.org/) to login into a javascript on a website?
I don't know exactly how to start with PhantomJs beacause I'm quite new in Python.
Or is there another (easyer) way?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Python doesn't really have anything to do with it. PyPhantomJS is the same as PhantomJS, except written in Python, and it has plugin support (REALLY useful). Check the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/FAQ) to see a little description of the 'differences'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CasperJS which is a wrapper around PhantomJS. You can do things such as click on a selector, submit a form, fill out a form, etc very easily.