# Login Test with PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have problem with my phantom Js code, as you see below, I have code to test my friend web server (make with node Js). Actually, it seem simple and perfectly runs.

> ```
> var page = require('webpage').create();
>
> var address   = "http://localhost:3333";
>
> // Route "console.log()" calls from within the Page context to the 
> // main Phantom context (i.e. current "this")
> page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
>   console.log("Console.log: ", msg);
> };
>
> page.onAlert = function(msg) {
>   console.log("Alert:", msg);
> };
>
> page.open(address, function (s) {
>     page.evaluate(function () {
>   function click(el){
>       var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
>       ev.initMouseEvent(
>       "click",
>       true /* bubble */,
>       true /* cancelable */,
>       window, null,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
>       false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
>       0 /*left*/, null
>       );
>       el.dispatchEvent(ev);
>   }
>   document.getElementById('username').value = 'MyName';
>   document.getElementById('password').value = 'MyWord';
>   click(document.querySelector('input[type=submit]'));
>     });
>
>     page.onNavigationRequested = function() {
>   // console.log("Moved", JSON.stringify(arguments))
>   // to check whether send or not
>   page.render("printscreen" + ".png");
>     };
>
>     setTimeout(function(){
>   page.render("nextprintscreen" + ".png");
>         phantom.exit();
>     }, 3000);
> });
> ```

**BUT**

when I declare 
`var userName = 'MyName';` 
`var passWord = 'MyWord';` 
then place it below 
`var address   = "http://localhost:3333";` 
and exchange 
`document.getElementById('username').value = 'MyName';`
`document.getElementById('password').value = 'MyWord';`
with 
`document.getElementById('username').value = userName;`
`document.getElementById('password').value = passWord;`

it return `invalid username or password` from my friend web server. Can you help me how to figure it out and why it happen. It's my first 'javascript world' code.

I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107331/login-to-a-webpage-using-phantomjs-and-jquery) and [another variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923242/login-to-javascript-with-python-phantomjs) then [a suggestion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phantomjs/20z8N8rwITw)

but it's just make me more confuse.

Thanks, 
Ahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `page.evaluate()` is sandboxed, and so has no access to the variables of your phantom script.

Since PhantomJS 1.6, JSON-serializable arguments can be passed to the `page.evaluate()`. 
The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a **simple primitive object**. However, an object can be serialized via JSON.

You can change your code to this :

```
page.evaluate(function (login, pwd) {
     ...
     document.getElementById('username').value = login;
     document.getElementById('password').value = pwd;
     ...
}, userName , passWord );
```